# How to save the state of AJAX application using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ria

I am just trying to dip my toes in this Ajax thing. I have a very basic question

I have seen the UI plugin(http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/drag) for jQuery, where you can drag and drop frames, stretch things, animate etc. So basically you get all the desktop features right in your web application.

In the desktop world, you can save the state of the objects to a file but how do you save the state of the manipulated objects in jQuery.

For e.g. If I drag a frame in jQuery, or stretch the borders of a div element, how do I save it to a file on the server so that next time, when I open, it remains modified?

Comment: You may want to look at [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/).  It's the official replacement to the old Interface library.

Answer (score 6):

Collect the state into an object, serialize it to [JSON](http://www.json.org), do an HTTP POST using [AJAX](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) to a script on your server which saves it appropriately.

Load it with the reverse method (you can skip the AJAX and print the JSON straight into your page as it loads though)

Comment: i wouldn't serialize to JSON, the jQuery ajax.post() function serializes to url-encoded, which is readily parsed by the server-side webapp

Answer (score 1):

Yes Nilesh - the [height()](http://jquery.bassistance.de/api-browser/#height) and [width()](http://jquery.bassistance.de/api-browser/#width) methods. I'm not aware of a native method that provides positional data, although there may well be a plug-in; failing that, some raw javascript should suffice some raw javascript should suffice.